# polymer and web animations

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have question about web-animations

http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/web-animations.html

I want to have an animation "freeze" in position after the animation is done. By default it appears to go back to it's original attributes

http://jsbin.com/qariw/1/edit

click on the grow button a few times to see the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, including some background around the web-animations project and it's affiliation with polymer if any?

## web-animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill: forwards` for your animation.

Web Animations spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations/

Comment: that worked, thanks!   BTW: I would not have gotten that from reading documentation on "forwards" but i guess it has multiple purposes.  I was also grepping code/docs on CSS equivalent : "freeze" and came up with nothing.